# Constraint based on relationship of two tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, constraints

Basically I want to only allow an edit/update in Table A when column in Table B is NULL. Table A and Table B reference the same primary key id. So something like;

```
-- Only allow Table A to be updated when Table B column is NULL

update TableA
set blah = @a, foo = @b
from tablea
inner join tableb on tablea.id = tableb.id
where tableb.column is null
```

Is there some way to use this as a constraint on Table A?

Comment: You can use trigger. What you mean by `tableb.column is null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Instead_Update_Table_A
ON TABLEA
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                FROM deleted d INNER JOIN TableB B
                ON d.PK_Column = B.PK_Column
                WHERE B.ColumnName IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Invalid update',16,1)
        RETURN;
    END

  -- Your update statement here 

END
```

Comment: If my update statement is in a stored procedure and is being called by the application, can I leave it as is, or do I have to put it in the trigger?

Comment: The answer is: "use inserted table to insert new values in target table, in the trigger".